# Use function pointer without knowing prototype at compiletime

Tags: c, linux, dlopen

From [this site](https://www.dwheeler.com/program-library/Program-Library-HOWTO/x172.html), I learned the very exciting fact that you can load and run code from a shared library without explicitly compiling your program with it.

The following snippet of code illustrates how to use `dlopen()` (and associated functions) to run the `double cos(double)` function from C's math library (libm):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    void *handle;
    double (*cosine)(double);
    char *error;

    handle = dlopen ("/lib/libm.so.6", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle) {
        fputs (dlerror(), stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    cosine = dlsym(handle, "cos");
    if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL)  {
        fputs(error, stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    printf ("%f\n", (*cosine)(2.0));
    dlclose(handle);
}
```

As a hobby, I've been writing an interpreter (in C) for a custom language and I'd like to make it possible for the user to select a shared library and run code from it. I know this is possible, since many languages (including Python and J, both written in C) can dynamically call functions using `dlopen()`, only knowing at runtime what will be passed to and returned from the function.

However, I won't be able to predict ahead of time how I will need to cast the void pointer returned from `dlsym()`. In the above code, the programmer knew that the symbol they were going to look up ("cos") was a function using one double as a parameter and returning a double, so they knew how they had to cast the `cosine` variable to "pointer to function taking in a double and returning a double".

If I wanted to write a program where the user would specify a filename AND the function prototype, how could I write the underlying C code that would call dlsym() and call the function correctly?

*My theory is that you would need to push parameters and pop return values from the process's stack directly (which I don't know how to do without inline assembly, which I'd like to avoid), but this is made complicated by the fact that you might need to pass a parameter through a register. Anyone know how to deal with this?*

Comment: Feels somewhat relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2820236/129570

Comment: The C language itself does not support this; it can only be done using assembly or other methods outside of C (possibly including external routines that do the necessary operations in assembly). Possibly the “easiest” way to do this would be that, once the user gives you the function prototype, your program writes, to a file, C source code that calls the function. That source code would be in the body of a function you design. Then you use routines like `system` to run the C compiler and other utilities, and you use `dlopen` to link the result into your program, then you call your routine.

Comment: Your routine would have a fixed parameter list, including a pointer to an array of `union`, where the `union` contains a member for each possible type you want to support. So you can pass arbitrary arguments to your routine through this array, and it calls the desired routine for you. This is all a crude kludge, generally useful only for learning and experimenting.

Comment: Languages such as Perl and Python place requirements on the interface of the functions they call. You can’t load an arbitrary C library and call its functions; you have to write or generate a glue layer that is callable by the scripting language and marshals arguments, calls the target C function, and handles the response appropriately.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes)

Comment: @n.m.: treat my comment as having 'or Python' removed.

Answer (score 3):

There is a well known library to solve this problem, used by many interpreted languages: [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/).

Internally, this library uses assembly code, of course, but it has so many HW and SW backends that you can consider it a *portable solution*.